# How to create documents in iCloud Drive?

Tags: ios8, icloud, uidocument, cloudkit

I have an application that creates `UIDocuments` on iCloud. I have used my apple account to upgrade to iCloud Drive, but I haven't been able to see those `UIDocuments` in my iCloud Drive folder.
How can I create documents in iCloud Drive? I want the user to be able to see those files in his folder.

Answer (score 2):

According to the document 'Design for documents in iCloud' from Apple if you dave a UIDocument then it ends up in the iCloud drive. See
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/iCloudDesignGuide/Chapters/DesigningForDocumentsIniCloud.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012094-CH2
There are lots of known issues where the conversion to iCloud drive resulted in the loss of documents. Try creating a new UIDocument and see if it ends up in iCloud drive.

Comment: I've just tried but again... no files neither app folder appears on my icloud.com account. I'm using _iOS 8_ and upgraded to _iCloud Drive_. Still can't see files created using `UIDocument`. Any other idea?

Comment: No more that that if you have set it up right it should end up there. Maybe this tutorial helps: http://www.raywenderlich.com/12779/icloud-and-uidocument-beyond-the-basics-part-1